# Can Tableau connect to arbitrary REST APIs as data sources?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to use a REST API as a data source for tableau.  Is this possible in any way?  The API service returns standard JSON, and I would think that would be an ideal scenario for tableau.  Rather than connecting to some backend database behind the API.

Thanks

Comment: http://community.tableau.com/ideas/1276. Take a look at Ashley Jaschke answer. Apparently there is a beta for that.

Answer (score 11):

The **web data connector** does this <strike>and is in beta right now</strike> as noted by inox. See: https://www.tableau.com/web-data-connector

> "The Web Data Connector will allow you to create a connection to almost any data that is accessible over HTTP. This can include internal web services, JSON data, REST APIs, and many other sources.  It will not be supported in the initial launch of Tableau 9.0. Beta participants will be able to use a dedicated product key to continue building and testing connectors until the Web Data Connector officially launches."

Also, you can use the **Extract API** to create Tableau Extracts from an API: https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/extract-api-introduction

Comment: I read the docs and tutorial and don't have a clue why a webpage is needed for this ...

Comment: Without web page, Is there any way?

Comment: No, the Web Data Connector must have a web page. You have to build a web page and create a button linking to the REST API. Then, paste the web page link to the Web Data Connector. (I did this before and it's very crazy lol) Currently, I use a tool called Acho to import data from API to tableau. It saves me lots of time on building meaningless web pages...